# OPTIONS and then POST executing action twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When I make a $http.post from my client to the web api on a different project, firebug and chrome both show an OPTIONS method and then a POST method.

**The problem**
Both request actually execute my API action. If I restrict to POST, the OPTIONS fails and the post never happens. I have CORS turned on in both angular and webapi.

my app.js has these lines:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

my api call:

```
    $scope.add = function () {
        var role = { Name: 'admin' };
        $http.post('http://localhost:7514/Roles/add', role).
            success(function () {
                alert('RolesController.add');
            }).
            error(function (message) {
                alert('FAILED EXECUTE RolesController.add');
            });
    };
```

the webapi web.config

```
<system.webServer>
...
<!-- added for cors handling, remove when using a dedicated cors handler or the system.web.cors dll-->
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Looking at your comment in web.config, are you using Web API CORS nightly package? Regarding your issue, you are looking for OPTIONS request not to execute the action but respond back with appropriate Access-Control headers so that the next POST request happens as expected?

Comment: @KiranChalla, No I'm not, because I couldn't get the myget reference working, because there were not any packages. In order to continue developing, I put the web.config custom headers there. The comment is a reminder to remove it, since I don't think the custom headers should be there if I use the nightly package. So the options should have been intercepted by a cors library?

Comment: If you use the nightly CORS package, the OPTIONS request gets intercepted by a message handler which doesn't execute the action, but still sends the appropriate response header. For more information and how to use nightly packages, you should look at this blog post regarding getting the CORS nightly package. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2013/04/05/try-out-asp.net-web-api-cors-support-using-the-nightly-builds.aspx

Comment: @KiranChalla, I've added the myget repo, but when I select it, there were no packages to download. I'll try again on Monday. I'm pretty sure you are right, so if you post an answer, I'll verify it on Monday and mark your post as the answer.

Comment: Make sure to select "Prerelease" from the the drop down.

Comment: @KiranChalla That works, please post an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the nightly CORS package, the OPTIONS request gets intercepted by a message handler which doesn't execute the action, but still sends the appropriate response header. For more information and how to use nightly packages, you should look at this blog post regarding getting the CORS nightly package.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2013/04/05/try-out-asp.net-web-api-cors-support-using-the-nightly-builds.aspx

Make sure to select "Prerelease" from the the drop down.

Comment: A new tutorial has been added to the web api documentation. They have integrated the nigtly cors changes into the main nuget repo. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api